# Где сейчас применяются блок-схемы?

Tags: блок-схема

Где **на сегодняший день** применяются блок-схемы?

Интересно узнать. А то у меня такое ощущение, что их используют только студенты для оформления контрольных работ. Я не говорю, что это плохо — просто где ещё?

---

И собственно ТО, о чём я хотел спросить первым делом (если надо, то оформлю как отдельный вопрос).

Какие **современные** требования к внешнему виду блок-схем?

Я нашёл в старой тетрадке лекцию (поэтому и вопросы возникли), в которой советский ГОСТ даёт чёткие указания по соотношению ширины и высоты элементов блок-схемы. Просмотрел картинки в Интернете — на тех, что попались, эти соотношения совсем не соблюдаются. Особенно на англоязычных ресурсах.

Comment: В обучении. С ними проще уложить в мозгу понимание, что такое алгоритм. Так считается. Ну и в разработке микросхем - там тоже используется.

Comment: Ну и в обсуждении сложных алгоритмов можно вполне набросать блок-схему. Набросать, а не начертить, конечно. Хотя, если вам в документации придётся описывать алгоритм, не писать же в терминах while/for/call? Так что тоже по идее может пригодиться блок-схема.

Answer (score 1):

Использую блок-схемы при разработке алгоритмов в Enterprise проектах (Java + PostgreSQL + PHP + JS). Очень полезная на практике вещь в построении сложных алгоритмов, которая экономит довольно много времени и помогает избегать многие ошибки. Так же наличие блок-схем значительно упрощает работу в команде с другими программистами.

Лично мы не придерживаемся стандартов, которым обучали в ВУЗе касательно ширины, высоты и т.д., т.к. в работе на такие мелочи обращать внимание нет времени и смысла. Ориентируемся по содержимому блоков. Но всё равно строго соблюдаем правила использования самих элементов схемы, соответствующих тому, что написано в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0).

Для построения блок-схем используем сервис [draw.io](http://draw.io)

Не далее, чем сегодня мне попалась на глаза статья на Хабре, где автор представляет алгоритм в виде понятных блок-схем, которые наглядно визуализируют описываемый код: [Битва дроидов и джедаев на клеточном автомате](https://habrahabr.ru/post/311196/)

Comment: Спасибо, интересно! *«Для построения блок-схем используем сервис draw.io»* Начало/конец (он же терминатор, terminal) там — это "rounded rectangle" или "ellipse"?

Comment: @Nikolja, обратите внимание на набор элементов Flowchart, там всё необходимое имеется.

Comment: *«Но всё равно строго соблюдаем правила использования самих элементов схемы»* Да вот с элементами тоже есть разночтения, так сказать. Ввод/вывод — кто-то рисует параллелограмм "Данные". А кто-то знак "Ручной ввод".  Интересно, например, как у вас на работе изображают **цикл**? Каким знаком/знаками?

Comment: @Nikolja, если очень упрощённо, то цикл изображаем вот так:http://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2016/09/3a3a4c42ad56e8c96b1c445d370ad3a7.png

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснения! Странно, я "плюсанул" ваш **ответ**, но кто-то уже успел -1 поставить без комментариев. Итого ноль вышло...

Answer (score 0):

Блок-схемы как минимум уже полвека никто не использует. Есть UML, но он используется редко, обычно в крупных проектах. Построение блок-схем - это рудимент образовательной системы ВУЗов (а вообще-то, вся оборазовательная система - рудимент). В школе, конечно, допустимо, чтобы дать базовые понятия об алгоритмах. Меня раздражало, что нас заставляли на первом и втором курсах заниматься этой ерундой. На практике код пишется сразу на каком-либо языке. Если программисты пишут на разных ЯП, но знают общий, то будут писать код на нём, а затем каждый перепишет на тот, что необходим. Если нет - будут использовать псевдокод.